# Scala: map and unzip list in one pass

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, collections, tuples

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
[(8, 3, 9), (10, 3, 0), (-37, 4, 1)]
```

I would like to map this list and simultaneously unzip it *in one pass*. Here is an example with two passes (or at least I strongly assume it takes two passes, if not then we're done here :D)

```
val l = List((8, 3, 9), (10, 3, 0), (-37, 4, 1))
val (list1, list2) = l.map({ el => (el._1, el._2) }).unzip
```

Of course I could just do this in an imperative style by looping over the lists and appending to a collection but is there a way to do this in a succinct functional way? I'm guessing I would essentially need a lazy `map` followed by an eager `unzip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always `fold`.

```
val (list1, list2) = l.foldRight((List.empty[Int],List.empty[Int])){
  case ((a,b,_),(l1,l2)) => (a::l1,b::l2)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very specific to your stated problem; it doesn't solve a more general problem.  Try:

```
val (list1, list2, _) = l.unzip3
```

---

#### Edit

To be fair, after locating the implementation `scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate.unzip3`, it's a very non-functional loop that builds 3 lists and returns them, pretty much as described in the original question.  At least it's one-pass and not just burying the two-pass.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `unzip` with a function

In Scala, the `unzip` operation takes as an implicit parameter a function to produce the pair so you can `map` and `unzip` in one go. Here is how it looks in [Scala 2.13.4 docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) for `List`:

```
def unzip[A1, A2](implicit asPair: (A) => (A1, A2)): (List[A1], List[A2])
```

By passing your own `asPair` function, you can accomplish the result you are looking for:

```
scala> val l = List((8, 3, 9), (10, 3, 0), (-37, 4, 1))
val l: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((8,3,9), (10,3,0), (-37,4,1))

scala> val (list1, list2) = l.unzip(el => (el._1, el._2))
val list1: List[Int] = List(8, 10, -37)
val list2: List[Int] = List(3, 3, 4)
```

### Algorithmic Complexity

The source code for the `unzip` function lives in trait `scala.collection.IterableOps` in file [`Iterable.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.4/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L775):

```
def unzip[A1, A2](implicit asPair: A => (A1, A2)): (CC[A1], CC[A2]) = {
  val first: View[A1] = new View.Map[A, A1](this, asPair(_)._1)
  val second: View[A2] = new View.Map[A, A2](this, asPair(_)._2)
  (iterableFactory.from(first), iterableFactory.from(second))
}
```

If I read it correctly, the list is actually traversed twice: once for each list produced.

However, in your original solution, the list was traversed three times: once for the `map` operation and twice for the `unzip` operation so my solution is still an improvement.

The solution using `foldRight` suggested by @jwvh seems to only traverse the list once but `foldRight` has an overhead of initially reversing the list (in order to take from the head of the list). So I guess my solution has exactly the same algorithmic complexity. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)